# PhpStorm Zero-Configuration Debugging not working for PHP 5.4.19

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using XAMPP version `v3.2.1` and here's the output of `php -v`:

```
PHP 5.4.19 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2013 01:12:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

I want to set up [Zero-Configuration Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html) with PhpStorm, so I followed all the steps (I think) and tried to launch a PHP file with breakpoints placed on it. But for some reason, when I open / refresh the page, it doesn't detect the breakpoint at all, nor it shows the `incoming connection` screen in PhpStorm.

I validated my setup here:

[image]

and I'm using https://github.com/BrianGilbert/xdebug-helper-for-firefox Firefox plugin.

I just want to simply debug my local PHP website as I browse through it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to troubleshoot it starting from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#debugger-cannot-connect and further down.

Answer (score 2):

You are using PHP 5.4. Please, for the love of god, upgrade. This, and Xdebug's 2.2, haven't been supported for half a decade. Neither PHP 5.4 or Xdebug 2.2 are supported any more, and not for a very long time.